# MySQL tuning query - 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, performance, percona, percona-server, performance-tuning

I'm using Percona Server 5.6.31 on RHEL 6. 64G RAM/16vCPU - VMware. It's Completely InnoDB and the database size is 300G.

I have set `Innodb_buffer_pool` to 52G, `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` to default (8) and `innodb_flush_method` to `O_DIRECT`. `Innodb_read_io_threads` and `write_io` threads are set to 64.

Memory utilization is above 90% most of the time. CPU utilization varies. Sometimes spikes. `vm.swappiness` is set to default (60).

I have two queries:

1. What should be my value for `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`? Is it right or is a change required?
2. I read many articles suggesting that swappiness needs to be set to 1 or 0 or 10 for MySQL database servers. But I do not observe any swapping on the OS. Do I need to still swappiness to 0 or 1. Is it better to change the value on proactive basis or I should change only when it swaps?

I can provide more info if required.

**Update:**

Show variables and Show global status output can be seen here [Config details](https://anotepad.com/note/read/ip56rw)

CPU utilization is often above 80%. Does CPU utilization only have to do with query tuning?

Comment: @RaymondNijland All InnoDB data is read through the buffer pool including data, not just secondary indexes.  Technically the data is in a clustered index, but I think the point of your comment was that only secondary indexes are stored in the buffer pool, which is incorrect.

Comment: @G-Nugget your right ive made a error innodb_buffer_pool_size hold table data and index data `InnoDB maintains a storage area called the buffer pool for caching data and indexes in memory` read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html.. ive edited my comment

Comment: As a rule of thumb, set your innodb_buffer_pool_size to approximately 70 – 80% of the RAM available.this value should be between 44,8 Gb and 51.2 Gb but 52GB should also work..

Comment: I think my question was not about what gets stored in buffer pool or what should be the buffer pool sizing.

Answer (score 1):

- swappiness:

  - = 0 --> crash if you run out of memory -- not nice
  - small --> best
  - large --> might swap mysql preemptively, leading to poor performance
- pool_instances -- should not be more than pool_size/1G; the specific value makes only a small difference in performance.  (Don't worry about it.)  Some say 16 should be the max number of instances, but I have not heard 'why'.
- CPU spikes -- *Usually* a missing index or a poorly phrased query.  Find it and fix it.  (And/or ask for advice)
- The buffer_pool(s) *cache* data and indexes.  It is (roughly) a least-recently-used cache.  It is also used for delaying index updates due to writes.
- 52G/64G -- reasonable.  It obviously can't hold the entire 300GB, but that may not be an issue -- especially if most of the action is in isolated portions.  Example:  Only "recent" data is actively accessed.  Counter example:  UUIDs have terrible performance when the data is bigger than the buffer_pool.

For further analysis of settings, post `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`.  (Not here; there is a size limitation.)

Comment: and just one more!  VMware(!!!) it good product, but high loading database server and virtualisation - it what need to avoid! You never will know - where the problem? it is "server" spike? or it is something other? I have a lot of examples about this.